# Referencing one field in order to delete row if you save the record

Tags: visualforce, validation, delete, saveresult

[image]

Just want to ask if it's possible to save the record on the first row if it's completely fill-up the 4 fields, and the 2nd row will be automatically deleted when there's no SkillName if you save that 2nd row. or in simple terms, skillName is the reference field in order to save the whole row. thanks in advanced!

Front End(VF Page)

```
<apex:column headerValue="Skill Name"><!--{!x}-->
                                 <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                                    <apex:inputField id="Skill" value="{!esw.esforWrapper.Skill_ID__c}" required="{!sNameRequired}">
                                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!isItRequiredSkl}" reRender="none" immediate="true"> 
                                            <apex:param name="sName" value="{!esw.esforWrapper.Skill_ID__c}" assignTo="{!skillName}" />
                                         </apex:actionSupport>

                                    </apex:inputField>
                                 </apex:outputPanel>
                             </apex:column>
```

Controller

```
      public void populateSkill(){
        Set<ID> empSkillIDSet = new Set<ID>();
        totalESList.clear();
        try{
            for (EmpSkillWrapper wc : esWrapper){
                Employee_Skills__c e1 = new Employee_Skills__c();

                if (wc.esforWrapper.Skill_ID__c != null) {
                    e1.Skill_ID__c = wc.esforWrapper.Skill_ID__c;
                }               

                if (wc.esforWrapper.Proficiency__c != null) {
                    e1.Proficiency__c = wc.esforWrapper.Proficiency__c;        
                }           

                if (wc.esforWrapper.Skill_Type__c != null) {
                    e1.Skill_Type__c = wc.esforWrapper.Skill_Type__c;
                }             

                if (wc.esforWrapper.Year_of_Experience__c != null) {
                    e1.Year_of_Experience__c = wc.esforWrapper.Year_of_Experience__c;                    
                }  

                if (e1.Skill_ID__c != null && e1.Proficiency__c != null && e1.Skill_Type__c != null && e1.Year_of_Experience__c != null) {
                    system.debug('esList ' + totalESList);
                    totalESList.add(e1); 
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e){

            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessages(e); 
        }

        for(Integer i=0; i<totalESList.size(); i++)
        {
            empSkillIDSet.add(totalESList.get(i).Skill_ID__c);
        }

        if(empSkillIDSet != null){
            if(empSkillIDSet.size() < totalESList.size()){

                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please remove duplicate skill');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                flag = true;
            }
        }  
    }

    public void isItRequiredSkl() {
    if (skillName == null) {
        clearLists();
        skillTypeRequired = false;
        yoeRequired = false;
        proficiencyRequired = false;              
    } 

    if (skillName != null) {
        skillTypeRequired = true;
        yoeRequired = true;
        proficiencyRequired = true;
    }



   }

    public void populateListsWithContactId(Contact contact){
        boolean isNotNull = false;
        if(totalESList != null){

            for(Employee_Skills__c es: totalESList){
                es.Employee_ID__c = contact.Id;
                isNotNull = true;
            } 
        }

        if (isNotNull == true){
            upsert totalESList;
        }
   }


    public void clearLists(){
        totalESList.clear();
    }

    public PageReference CreateProfileTab6(){

        flag=false;
        try{

            if((esWrapper.get(0).esforWrapper.Skill_ID__c != null) &&
                (esWrapper.get(0).esforWrapper.Skill_Type__c != null) &&
                (esWrapper.get(0).esforWrapper.Proficiency__c != null) &&
                (esWrapper.get(0).esforWrapper.Year_of_Experience__c != null)){
                populateSkill();
            } 


            if(!flag){
                    // customSecQuest is just an security question to fill-up
                    customSecQuest();
                    c.AccountId = '0012800001B2ofk'; 
                    insert c;
                    populateListsWithContactId(c);
                    pageRef = new PageReference('/'+c.Id); 
                    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            }else{
                pageRef = new PageReference(PAGE_CREATE_NEW_PROFILE); 
                pageRef.setRedirect(false);  
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            clearLists(); 
        } 

        pageRefresh = true;
        return pageRef;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code which your approach. By the way your requirement is achievable.

Comment: Hi @SantanuBoral  how could I edit my post here? so that I could attached my codes together with the picture. thanks!

Comment: you can see the "edit" link to edit to question

Comment: You can have validation rule to mandate the Skill Type and then while inserting the records use [Database.Insert(yourList, false);](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) Records which don't pass the validation rule will not be inserted anyway, rest will be inserted.

Comment: @SantanuBoral but the thing is, I have a reference object before I could save this skill, I must have a Personal Info record, and eventhough I've not set an skill, I could still save Personal Info. So I must not mandate it to required, is it possible?